# How to send a list through TCP sockets - Python

Tags: python, list, sockets, tcp

I want to send a list through TCP sockets but i can't get the exact list when receiving from the server-side .
To be more specific say that i have this list:

```
 y=[0,12,6,8,3,2,10]
```

Then, i send each item of the list like this:

```
 for x in y :
 s.send(str(x))
```

Now the code of server to recieve the data looks like this:

```
 while True:
 data = connection.recv(4096)
 if data:
 print('received "%s"' % data)             
 else:
 print('no more data from', client_address)
 break
```

The problem is that when i run the program i don't get the same list but something like this:

data=[012,6,83,210]

Also, everytime i run the program i get a different result for list data

Any ideas what's going wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `pickle` or `json` to send list(or any other object for that matter) over sockets depending on the receiving side. You don't need `json` in this case as your receiving host is using python.

```
import pickle
y=[0,12,6,8,3,2,10] 
data=pickle.dumps(y)
s.send(data)
```

Use `pickle.loads(recvd_data)` on the receiving side.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: Did you mean a weird string? If then wait for some time, n I will add a little more explanation or you can read the docs. If you understand pickle and still getting something weird then please describe it.

Comment: Yes i get a weird string. I just read the docs you posted , and understood why i need to use pickle. However, i can't really describe that weird thing..

Comment: I used `pickle.loads(connection.recv(4096))` on the receiving side but i get an EOFError. 

Used try-except but the else statement never gets true

Comment: Its because data is not received completely on the receiving side. Try putting `connection.recv(4096)` inside a loop and loop till you have received the complete data.

Comment: Do you know anything about Reed-Solomon Code ?

Comment: No, never heard of it. But will read up on it as soon as I get time.

Comment: Can you give an example, giving an input and corresponding output.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for my extremely late response, but I hope this can help anyone else who has this problem. This may not be the best solution, but I would convert the list into a string, and encode and send that string. Then, the receiving end can receive, decode, and convert this string back into a list using `eval()`. This would look something like this:

Sender:

```
y = [0,12,6,8,3,2,10] 
# Convert To String
y = str(y)
# Encode String
y = y.encode()
# Send Encoded String version of the List
s.send(y)
```

Receiver:

```
data = connection.recv(4096)
# Decode received data into UTF-8
data = data.decode('utf-8')
# Convert decoded data into list
data = eval(data)
```

Comment: this seems to me like an open door to all sorts of malicious code injections

Answer (score -1):

you can use **NetStructer** module it's provide the way to send list,str,tupple and more .... .
here a simple code

```
from NetStructer import Bridge

addr = ('192.168.1.4',71) # the address of the server that's you want to connect

bridge = Bridge.Link(addr)# use Bridge class to connect to server with address

bridge.SendBuffer([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10])
```

Comment: Is this your product? How is anyone supposed to find it? Does it have documentation?

Comment: Welcome, and please highlight what your answer adds to the already accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38413006/12846804 from seven years ago. See [answer] for guidance.